# Animate an image to go off-screen, and hide it when it's gone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$('.container').append('<img class="spinning-coin-image" src="img/coin-spinning-transparent.gif" style="position:absolute; top:50px">');

   function coinLeft() {
      $(".spinning-coin-image").animate({left: "-=5100"}, 5000, "swing", coinRight);
   }
   function coinRight() {
      $(".spinning-coin-image").animate({left: "+=5000"}, 5000, "swing", coinLeft);
   }

   coinRight();
```

I'm trying to find a way to take my image, `coin-spinning-transparent.gif`, and animate it so it flies off screen, and then re-appears. 
The problem I found is that 1, if you have more than 5000 horizontal pixels, it won’t actually go off-screen, and 2, this seems really inefficient.

Comment: Use `right:-widthOfImage`

Comment: Just `fadeOut` and set to `display:none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something to go off screen undependently of the screen size, calculate that size:

```
var out_width =  $(window).width();
```

Then just animate anything to that point.

```
function coinLeft() {
      $(".spinning-coin-image").animate({left: out_width}, 5000, "swing", coinRight);
   }
   function coinRight() {
      $(".spinning-coin-image").animate({left: 0}, 5000, "swing", coinLeft);
   }
```

check [jQuery's width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) method basics and variants.

Answer (score -1):

why won't you get the width of window and store it into some variable and then use it

```
var window_width =  $(window).width();
```

like u used it before

```
 function coinLeft() {
      $(".spinning-coin-image").animate({left: window_width*(-1)+"px"}, 5000, "swing", coinRight);
   }
```

maybe that will help

Comment: Is it neccesary to set "px" to the left animation value? jQuery's units is universally pixels

Comment: well it is true that jquery automatically adds unit px to most of properties, but to make it more clear i used it here

Comment: That is not making it clear, that's adding useless code, and the result of concatenating the px with the +, the several "" and so makes the result be quite less clear than just mentioning window_width. If jQuery does not need the units, just don't mention them

Comment: five more chars makes no difference in this function, but if it bothers you so much, just don't write it